# Is 'feasibility' a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created [feasibility](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feasibility) for [Could a partial space elevator be practical and useful?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/260/could-a-partial-space-elevator-be-practical-and-useful), but I am wondering if such would be a useful tag. (I do not remember if I read the article/blog post about the evils of meta tags, but I am somewhat concerned that [feasibility](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feasibility) might be a meta tag or at least too general.)

(I will reiterate: I stink at tagging!)

Comment: We already have [engineering], which borders on this

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to give a name, but it seems like there should be a category for stuff that's on the limit of today's conceptual technology, which would be a better tag than feasibility. But I'm not sure what to name that tag...

Per Undo, I'll suggest the [conceptual](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conceptual) for such operations.

Comment: [conceptual], maybe?

Comment: @Undo: I like that idea.

Comment: Now to try to get 500 so I can make it happen...

Comment: @Undo: I just requested the change, I should be at 500 soon anyways, so...

Comment: This is quite a race to the top!

Answer (score 1):

Space business is littered with "feasibility studies". In a way, they mostly investigate the "financial feasibility" rather than technological feasibility. If we were to reflect this business as it is today, we would need to find a way to incorporate this work somehow in a tag, no matter how uncomfortable this may be.